# mysql count, distinct, join? Confusion

Tags: mysql, join, count

i have 2 tables:

```
tblItems 
ID           |     orderID             | productID
1                   1                     2
2                   1                     2
3                   2                     1
4                   3                     2

tblProducts
productID    |     productName
1                   ABC
2                   DEF
```

im attempting to find the most popular Product based on whats in "tblItems", and display the  product Name and the number of times it appears in the tblItems table.

i can get mysql to count up the total like:

$sql="SELECT COUNT(productID) AS CountProductID FROM tblItems";

but i can't figure out how to join the products table on..if i try LEFT JOIN the query goes horribly wrong

hopefully thats not too confusing..thankss

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you simply trying to find the count of orders by product like so:

```
Select P.ProductName, Count(*)
From tblItems As I
    Join tblProducts As P
        On P.ProductId = I.ProductId
Group By P.ProductName
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be looking for something like:

```
SELECT tblProducts.productName, COUNT(tblItems.ID)
FROM tblProducts
LEFT JOIN tblItems USING(productID)
GROUP BY tblProducts.productID
```

Comment: oh wow that works almost perfectly, thank you! it does return all products however, even if they don't appear in "tblItems". But it does count everything as i wanted. thanks.

Comment: @Alex Martelli - I'm a bit surprised this query runs. You have productName in the SELECT statement but not in the GROUP BY.

Comment: @Thomas, mysql is traditionally relaxed in this regards -- it just gives you any one value of the field in the group's records (so it's fine when all such values are identical, like here). I wouldn't recommend it in _standard_ SQL of course;-).

Comment: @calum, if you *don't* want products that don't appear in the table items, just drop the word `LEFT` from the query -- you specifically mentioned `LEFT JOIN` so of course I thought you **did** want them!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT count(i.productID) AS cnt, p.productName FROM tblItems AS i
LEFT JOIN tblProducts AS p ON p.productID = i.productID
GROUP BY i.productID
ORDER BY cnt desc
```